# PCRE regex replace a text pattern within double quotes

Tags: regex, notepad++, pcre

In Notepad++ 6.5.1 I need to replace certain patterns within quote pairs. I want to save the replace as part of a macro, so all replacements need to happen in one step.

For example, in the following string, replace all 'a' characters within quote pairs with a dash, while leaving characters outside the quote pairs untouched:

Input: `aa"bbabaavv"kdjhas"bbabaavv"x`

Desired result: `aa"bb-b--vv"kdjhas"bb-b--vv"x`

Note that the quotes are matched up pairwise, such that the 'a' in `kdjhas` is untouched.

So far I have tried searching for `(?:"[^"a]*|\G)\Ka([^"a]*)` and replacing with -$1, but that simply replaces all the a's, with the result `--"bb-b--vv"kdjh-s"bb-b--vv"x`. I'm attempting PCRE regex that will let me recursively replace the quote-delimited text.

**Edit**: Quote marks within a quoted string are escaped with an extra quote, e.g. "". However, assume I will have already replaced these in a previous pass with a special character. Therefore a regex solution to this problem will not have to deal with escaped quotes.

Comment: "Note that the quotes are matched up pairwise, such that the 'a' in kdjhas is untouched." I don't understand this. Is there a possibility for quotes in a quoted string?

Comment: Good question. The answer is yes, but if they occur they'll be escaped with another double quote, e.g. "bla bla ""blub"" blablabla"

Comment: @JohnDewey [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440015/variable-length-masking-with-preg-replace), I think it might be possible but it will be a pain. I'm tired right now to seriously look into it (3am)...

Comment: That's a lot to put into a single regular expression. You're certain this can't somehow be broken up with your macro, such that it could be done in multiple steps (multiple regexes)?

Comment: @aliteralmind yes I will have already cleaned those up - please see my edit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data have variable number of occurrences of quoted strings, then it is **not possible** to perform replacements only via regex at least in its form offered by Notepad++.

To replace using regex, you would need to perform regex find in existing regex match. As far as I know such a functionality is not available in Notepad++ regexes.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell if this is possible as you've only provided one line of input text.

But assuming that input follows this pattern:

```
BOL|any text|string with two groups of a's|any text|string with two groups of a's|any text|EOL
    aa       "bbabaavv"                    kdjhas   "bbabaavv"                    x
```

I was able to create this regexp search string:

```
^(.+?\".+?)([a]+)(.+?)([a]+)(.*?\")(.+?\".+?)([a]+)(.+?)([a]+)(.*?\".*)$
```

With this replace string:

```
\1-\3-\5\6-\8-\A
```

and it turn your input string from this:

```
aa"bbabaavv"kdjhas"bbabaavv"x
```

into this:

```
aa"bb-b-vv"kdjhas"bb-b-vv"x
```

Now naturally the search an replace will fail if the input varies from that pattern described as the search is looking for those four groups of a's inside the two groups of quoted strings.

Also I tested that regexp using Zeus which can create a regexp with more than 9 groups.

As you can see the regexp requires 10 groups.

I'm not familar with Notpad++ so I don't know if it supports that many groups.

Comment: The target string won't follow a fixed pattern, other than the quotation pairs. So I need a more general solution. For example, replace aa"bbabavv"kdjhas"cabab"blabla"foobar"fud with aa"bb-b-vv"kdjhas"c-b-b"blabla"foob-r"fud

Comment: As the pattern does not repeat I'd take a look using something like *SED* or *AWK* to do the search and replace.

Answer (score 0):

**Self-answer**

I may have been reaching for the stars in trying to get Notepad++ to do this regex replace, but I think I found a workaround.

The actual task I was attempting involved creating a SQL Server VALUES list from an Excel spreadsheet, where I was copying and pasting selected cells into Notepad++. The delimiters are \t and \r\n. But, cells can have linefeeds too, which are delimited by ". So, I was going to replace these linefeeds with `<br>` (or something like it), so that

```
"line1
line2"
```

would become `"line1<br>line2"`, before processing the actual end-of-row line feeds.

Having such parsing work reliably, especially when more than two lines were in a single cell, may have been too much to ask of Notepad++'s regex capability.

So I came up with a workaround that seems to be working:) Basically it starts with selecting a blank "dummy" column to the right of my column selection (which I can insert if I'm partially selecting from the middle). This will leave a trailing \t at the end of each row, which effectively sets these EOL's apart from ones that might exist with a text cell, freeing me from having to parse line feeds from a "..." field.

So I compiled a macro from the following steps, which seems to be working well:

1. replace `'` with `''`
2. replace `\t\r\n` with `'\)\r\n, \('`
3. replace `\t` with `', '`
4. replace `""` with `''`
5. replace `"` with `<blank>`
6. replace `^` with `\('` (cleanup - first row only)
7. replace `^, \('$` with `<blank>` (cleanup - last row only)

Example transformation:
from

```
line1   line 2  
"line3
line3b
line3c" line 4
```

to

```
('line1', 'line 2')
, ('line3
line3b
line3c', 'line 4')
```

which can now be easily modified into a `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES('line1', 'line 2')
, ('line3
line3b
line3c', 'line 4')
) t(a,b)
```