# Regex match whole words between quotes

Tags: regex

Am attempting to use Regex to match only whole words within double quotations.  These are the two statements I have and an example set of text. Looking to combine these 2 regex statements.

```
"(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*"
\b\w+\b
```

[image: img]

Trying to get this final output:

[image: otpt]

Ignore the zzz's, those are replacements of single quotes.  Bonus to anyone who recognizes this book.

Thanks a ton, apologies for potential confusion - first time asking a question here.

Edit: Solved - apologies for the confusing question and images, am using Python 2.7.  Used the regex linked to from @HamZa and modified for Python 2.7 and to ignore newlines.

(?:"?)\w+(?=(?:(?:[^"]"){2})*(?:[^"]*?"[^"]*?(?:$)))

goo.gl/VHvS2o

Comment: We're not fan of images to share input. Please use something like http://regex101.com which allows you to save and share a link. Also try to use the formatting tools. Also what language are you using? I guess you will need some black magic like `\G` & `\K`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir_Gibbie

Comment: Here's a small [regex](http://regex101.com/r/jJ8mY5), it doesn't support escaped quotes. I got the calculation of quotes part from a previous [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21443230). You will need either PCRE/php or Perl. Now seriously, why don't you just use 2 regexes :)

Comment: @HamZa Wow, HamZa, that's some serious action there, man!... Still operating ninja-style, under the cloak of darkness? If you post an answer it will get upvoted to the moon. :)

Comment: Thank you all a ton, the regex you linked to @HamZa I was able to modify a bit and get to work for Python 2.7.  (?:"*?)\w+(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*(?:[^"]*?"[^"]*?(?:$)))   http://goo.gl/VHvS2o.

Comment: Also @hjpotter92 that's right!  Sir Gibbie, by George Macdonald.  Great piece of practical theology - CS Lewis respected him hugely.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use two expressions as you suggest. This will extract strings inside double quotes:

```
/"[^"]+"/g
```

Then loop through the results of the first expression, passing them to the second to extract only word matches:

```
/\w+/g
```

Beware though that languages differ greatly in their implementation of word characters. JavaScript for example has very poor support for international characters, but for English, this should be fine. Should you need to support a larger character set, this expression might be a good replacement for the second one, but you will need to do your own testing with the material you are handling:

```
/[^" ]+/g
```

If you happen to be working in, say PHP or Java which do support lookbehind/lookahead matching, you might be able to combine the two operations into one expression, but usually those are more error prone and harder to debug. That's why I would recommend going for a split solution.

Comment: Thanks @nordhagen - it was Python 2.7, which doesn't support the \k like you mentioned.  Was able to get around it and will see if it works for the whole text.  Was hoping to not have to do 2 regex's and then have to re-insert quoted text back into the original, and I think I can do that now, but we'll see.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of other users who thought your question meant something else (and want to know how to do it), I'm going to answer what they might have thought it meant, but I realize this isn't what you're looking for (the other answer will probably suffice for that, I hope):

I do regular expressions in Python 3.x, and I don't know what you're using. So, that's why my answer is Python. Here's an example of how to find and replace only whole words within double quotes, in Python 3.4:

```
import re
s='"Okay", "this" is a "test"'
re.sub(r"(\")\b\S+\b(\")", r"\1~\2", s)

#The result is this string: '"~", "~" is a "~"'
```

This works if each word, and only one word, is enclosed in double quotes (without punctuation).

For what you actually meant, if the other answer doesn't suffice, you could use positive lookahead and lookbehind regular expression to include the quotes before and after (using whitespace touching the quote as a guideline to help the computer recognize when it's outside the quotes, seeing as there usually isn't whitespace directly after a double quote inside the quotation, and there usually is outside of it). You might need to do some other stuff to get it to work. If a two-step method is easier, I definitely recommend it! (Unless you're just wanting to learn new stuff.) I think the lookaheads and lookbehinds might be greedy, too. So be careful of that. Hopefully someone has a simpler answer, or a working example for you.

Examine this URL for explanations of lookaheads and lookbehinds, if you're not familiar with them:
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html

You might want to consider another alternative than regular expressions, too, if possible. Various HTML tools probably have some stuff to help you make functionality like this, seeing as they use opening and closing tags (similar to opening and closing quotes) and are probably used to manipulating things inside them.

Comment: For instance, you could find the first two double quotes in the string. Then, get their indexes and search only between those indexes for whole words. Then get the first two double quotes after the ending index and so on and so forth.

Comment: Thank you much @user2962794 for clearing up my confusing question.  I used a modified \k (so it would work in Python) and lookahead like you suggested.